# Flutter - How to reset Autocomplete list after fetching data from server?

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I have Autocomplete list:

```
List<CompanyName> companyNames = <CompanyName>[
    const CompanyName(name: 'No Data'),
  ];
```

And this works, only one item `No Data` is on the array, but that array is filled by data from the server, and the problem is when you press autocomplete on start you will see the `No Data` item on the list, after server fetching data, the list will not be updated by data from the server.

My idea is to create a local variable that will be updated by the `async` call, and that variable should hide autocomplete list before the server responds, or refresh the (re-render) widget after fetching...

```
Autocomplete<CompanyName>(
 optionsBuilder:
  (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
      return companyNames.where((CompanyName companyName) {
          return companyName.name.toLowerCase().contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
}).toList();
},
optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,  AutocompleteOnSelected<CompanyName>
    onSelected,
    Iterable<CompanyName> options) {
       return Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Material(
            child: ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 280,),
             child: SizedBox(width: 280,                                                  
                     height: companyNames.length <= 1 ? 80 : 280,
             child: ListView.builder(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: options.length, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {                                                                                        final CompanyName option = options.elementAt(index);
return GestureDetector(
onTap: () {                                                                                         onSelected(option);                                                                                        },
                                                                                          child: ListTile(                                                                                          title: Text(option.name, style: TextStyle(color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
                                                                                          ),
                                                                                        );
                                                                                      })))));
                                                                },
                                                                fieldViewBuilder:
                                                                    (context,
                                                                        controller,
                                                                        focusNode,
                                                                        onEditingComplete) {
                                                                  return TextFormField(
                                                                      controller:
                                                                          controller,
                                                                      focusNode:
                                                                          focusNode,
                                                                      onEditingComplete:
                                                                          onEditingComplete,
                                                                      keyboardType:
                                                                          TextInputType
                                                                              .text,
                                                                      autocorrect:
                                                                          false,
                                                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                                          isDense: true,
                                                                          hintText: "Company Name",
                                                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                                BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                                          ),
                                                                          fillColor: isDarkMode ? const Color(0XFF212124) : Colors.white,
                                                                          filled: true),
                                                                      validator: (value) {
                                                                        if (value ==
                                                                                null ||
                                                                            value.isEmpty) {
                                                                          return 'Please enter company name';
                                                                        } else {
                                                                          setState(
                                                                              () {
                                                                            client =
                                                                                value;
                                                                          });
                                                                        }
                                                                        return null;
                                                                      });
                                                                },
                                                                onSelected:
                                                                    (CompanyName
                                                                        selection) {
                                                                  setState(() {
                                                                    brokerCompany =
                                                                        selection
                                                                            .name;
                                                                  });
                                                                },
                                                                displayStringForOption:
                                                                    (CompanyName
                                                                            option) =>
                                                                        option
                                                                            .name,
                                                              ),
```

What is the best option and where is the best option to put the variable and re-render `Autocomplete()`?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html  as there was no info on ur async server fucntion.